# Result Error while writing a membership testing function in python 3

Tags: string, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I was trying to write a membership testing function in python using a list and a number. But it's not yielding the desired result. I am expecting to get True or False, but it shows 'None'. Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Here's what I wrote in the code:

```
def bln(x,num):
    x = []
    num = int()
    if (num in x):
        return True

num = 4
x = [i for i in range (1,5)]
print(x)
y = bln(x,num)
print(y)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
None
```

Comment: Why is your function overwriting the values of its parameters?

Comment: whatever x you are passing to the function you are overwriting it by using x = []

Comment: @Aran-Fey, I am new to programming, I didn't understand your question, Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overwritten the function parameters, therefore you are not using the values that you are passing. This is the correct way:

```
def bln(x,num):
    if (num in x):
        return True
```

To clarify what you where doing wrong.
Let's take for example a function that multiplies two numbers:

```
def multiply_numbers(x,y):
    return x*y

print(multiply_numbers(3,5)) #15 - all good, numbers are correctly multiplied

def multiply_numbers(x,y):

    # x parameter is overwritten here, and will ALWAYS have this values,
    #no matter what value you pass when you call the function
    x = 5 
    y = 5
    return x*y

print(multiply_numbers(3,5)) #25 - with every input you pass
```

Comment: Solved.Thank You. This mistake shows my lack of understanding.

Comment: It's not really solved. The function will still return `None` if there's no `num` in `x`.

Comment: The condition says: if a number is contained inside x, return true: if (num in x):  return True. If there is no num in x (x = [ ]), the condition won't be satisfied. What would you want it to return if there's no num in x?

Comment: For that, I would use an else statement and return False.